# Setting up Laravel in my framework: A facade root has not been set

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been using and setting up Laravel ORM in my framework and have hit upon this error: `A facade root has not been set.`

I currently have database functionality with working code however other classes such as Crypt and Schema throw this error. See my implementation below.

*Edit:* Here is a one-script example with the problem displayed:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
include('vendor/autoload.php');

$capsule = new Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
    'database'  => '*********',
    'username'  => '*********',
    'password'  => '*********',
    'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);
        
// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();

class GameDatabase extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function up()
    {
        
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            // table properties
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';  
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
            
            // table columns
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 64)->unique();
            $table->string('email', 128)->unique();
            $table->string('countryCode', 4);
            $table->string('mobile', 14)->unique();
            $table->string('password', 40);
            $table->string('password', 40);
            $table->boolean('verified');
            $table->dateTime('verifiedTime', 0);
        });
    }
 
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('flights');
    }
}

$db = new GameDatabase();
$db->up();
?>
```

Here is `composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/annotations": "1.13.2",
        "symfony/yaml": "^5.4",
        "symfony/cache": "^5.4",
                "doctrine/cache": "^1.11",
        "illuminate/database": "^9.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
    }
}
```

Any advice here appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very confused, why are you trying to "implement" part of the framework?

Comment: I am trying to use Eloquent out of the context of Laravel inside a PHP framework. The one-file example gives a complete overview of everything that is being done.

Comment: I'am using part of Laravel components in our custom framework and Eloquent is one of them and setting it is very straight forward. You don't need to use any Facades and as mentioned by @Tomasz simply call `Capsule::schema()` instead "Schema" facade and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use `Capsule::schema()` instead of `Schema` facade.

Comment: Would I do `use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;`?

Comment: Simply changing the values did not work.

Answer (score -2):

Add in your `bootstrap/app.php` this line: `$app->withFacades();` please.

Comment: I think you want me to initiate a Laravel instance, I’ll have a look. Literally, the one-script example is all the code executed.

Comment: This will only work when you install lumen framework and initialize `$app` with `Laravel\Lumen\Application` class but I guess OP only needs to use Eloquent ORM so why need to have lumen framework and set it up.